# When querying database all I get is false

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

So here's what I'm doing. I'm getting string from a page, and checking if it exists in my database. So here's what I got

```
//Get content
$token = file_get_contents('http://'.$url.'/'.$token.'.html');  

//Check if token exists
$smnt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM verify WHERE token = :token");
$smnt->bindValue(':token', $token);
$smnt->execute();
```

Now when I do

```
var_dump($smnt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

All I get is

```
bool(false)
```

The `token` is in the database, I checked multiple times. Any ideas?

Comment: Is Token a string?   Do you need quotes around it?

Comment: @Sparky He's using a prepared statement, no need for quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I don't work with mySQL, so I wasn't sure....

Comment: Doesn't it work the same way with parametrized statements in other databases?

Comment: Maybe when you read from the file, there's an extra newline at the end, but it isn't in the database. Does it work better if you use `$token = trim($token);`?

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of `$token` (like with `echo $token`) to make sure it's what you're expecting?

Comment: Yes I have @AlliterativeAlice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$token = trim(file_get_contents('http://'.$url.'/'.$token.'.html'));
```

to remove extraneous newlines and other whitespace around the token.